# net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers

Tags: corda

OS: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Corda: 4.4

I wanted to learn CordaRPCOps so I started by using the [template’s](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java) Cordform deployNodes task that provides me with three running nodes.

First I used the following code running locally to connect to PartyA’s Corda node.

```
NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort("localhost", 10006);
CordaRPCClient client = new CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress);
CordaRPCConnection connection = client.start("user1", "test");
CordaRPCOps cordaRPCOps = connection.getProxy();
```

This worked great.

Then I tried connecting from a different PC on the same network with the following change:

```
NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort("192.168.1.149", 10006);
```

This failed with the following error:

```
net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
```

Assuming this was network related I went back to the local PC and ran the same code:

```
NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort("192.168.1.149", 10006);
```

This also failed.  So I decided to try the PC name instead of the IP address.  This failed both locally and on the other PC.

Answer (score 0):

If the rpcSettings in the node.conf file use “localhost”:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10006"
    adminAddress="localhost:10046"
}
```

…you cannot connect to the node using anything but “localhost” or “127.0.0.1”

```
NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort("localhost", 10006);
```

This also means you cannot connect to the node from across the network.

If you replace “localhost” with the IP address or the computer name:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="192.168.1.149:10006"
    adminAddress="localhost:10046"
}
```

… then you can reference the node by either IP or computer name locally, or from another PC on the network:

```
NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort("192.168.1.149", 10006);
```

You’ll notice the change on the opening screen of the Node Shell when they start and list their respective information.

```
--- Corda Open Source 4.4 (21e8c4f) -------------------------------------------------------------


Logs can be found in                    : F:\corda\Java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs
! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:7006/jolokia/
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10005
RPC connection address                  : 192.168.1.149:10006
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10046
```

Comment: Note: you could (and probably should) just change the deployNodes task in the build.gradle file.  You would then need to re-run: 

./gradlew deployNodes for linux 
gradlew.bat deployNodes  for windows

This would update the node.conf automatically.

Comment: Note: instead of using your IP or computer name it might be better to use: address("0.0.0.0:10006") in the deployNodes task in your build.gradle file.